# Is it possible to log into a site then read information off the site under that user - in PHP?

Tags: php, session, authentication, curl

Question:
Is it possible to log into a site then read information off the site under that user (in PHP)?

example:
Many websites are dynamic and have php drawing information from databases. Lets say example.com had a login.

While logged in the page example.com/test.php displayed: "hello user", and when not logged in would display : "you're not a user sign in here"

Lets say the authentication process was through sessions, the user would login by posting a form with tags "user" and "pass" if correct would start a session that would allow the user to see the message for them on example.com/test.php

Question:
Is it possible to log into a site then read information off the site under that user?

I've been looking around and am not sure how to approach this. Anything would help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is "yes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can (with curl)

```
        $ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
        $ch = curl_init("http://example.com/index.php");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $output = curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close($ch);


        $ch = curl_init();
        $fields = array(
                'username' => 'genesis',
                'pass' => 'pass',
                'other' => 'post fields'
        );
        foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/login.php");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/logged_page.php");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        $needed_information = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use file_get_contents+streams and/or curl to fetch the data in PHP. There's libraries to allow you to execute javascript within php, so even dynamic pages could be handled.

The question is, is whatever you're trying to do worth all the work of basically building a browser within PHP.

Answer (score 0):

PHP [can do this](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch20_01.htm) but wasn't designed for that purpose.

PHP syntax is based on Perl, which might be better suited. You might also try Python.

Answer (score 0):

If [domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name) A,B where A != B, then you can't do this because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)(easily). You could ook into [SSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on). There are some libraries available, which I have not yet tried like for example => http://www.jasny.net/articles/simple-single-sign-on-for-php/